# Communicating to a RTD Server in Java instead of Excel

Tags: java, database, excel, real-time-data, rtd

I have a RTD plugin that provides an Excel sheet with Real Time Data of prices. However, I want to avoid the Excel link and I would like to directly communicate to the RTD server with a Java program such that I can retrieve data and send it to a database. I have seen examples of doing this in C#, but not in Java yet. Does anyone have a clue on how to set this up?